# check if path name has "#" with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a simple HTML + CSS + JavaScript tiny site, in which I am trying to open a new tab on click - where it opens the same url, but in that tab window redirects to another url.

Basic idea to make a pop-under.

So, I am opening on `href="index.html#"` - and I have put # sign just to make difference with original (first time opened) page, so I could make some changes in again opened page. sign appears on address bar and everything works ok. Except - here is a problem:

- `window.location.pathname` does not recognize the "#" sign

Don't want to use cookies or anything like that - need it to be very light.

Comment: `window.location.hash` will give you # value.

Comment: Thank you Parth Trivedi. - I just need to add this: hash must have something behind # - the "#" sign is not registered with .hash command - however, this do the job for me. Thanks again

Comment: if you found my answer helps you appreciate it by vote up.

Comment: Would love to - already tried - I need some 15 exp to do that - I am a newbie here :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take path `href="index.html#tab"`

```
//get hash value
var hashValue = window.location.hash;

//check for hash value
if(hashValue!=undefined && hashValue=="#tab")
{
      //do thing 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
        href="#" 
thats what my tester was and it went to same url but with a # sign

such as

```
`<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS Layouts</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <h1>My Page</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col1"></div>
        <div class="col2"></div>
        <div class="col2"></div>
    </div>

    <footer></footer>

</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: that should work for ya, no need to specify the file name just href="#"